# Executing a sql server query containing clause " where col like N'myStr%' " from java using spring

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, unicode

my query works using sql server management studio. However I can not get the query to work with named parameters and springsJDBCTemplate.

So actual sql required that works fine :

```
select colA from table1 where colb like N'lem%'
```

and a snippet of what I have tried :

```
String paramA = "N'lem%'";

select colA from table1 where colb like :paramA
```

I am using springs namedParamterJDBCTemplate. The N specifies nvarchar and unicode encoding as the actual parameters are encoded in foreign languages, eg cyrillic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N' is useful when presenting some text to the textual SQL parser in SSMS, but when you are using parameterised queries through spring, `DON'T`!  The string itself should be in Unicode, and the framework with handle it for you by declaring the parameter as NVarchar as well as marshalling the param properly.

```
String paramA = "lem%";
```

I don't believe you should even have the single quotes in the string, which I understand you're including only because of the N' notation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try escape sequence for

```
String paramA = "N\'lem%'";
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html